# Fallo "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." al abrir un Alert Dialog en Android

Tags: android

¡Buenos días compañeros!

En medio del proyecto que estoy desarrollando en Android, quiero que cuando pulsen una imagen, al despulsarla salga un cuadro de dialogo pidiendo confirmación:

Este es el código que tengo para abrir la imagen:

```
imgaccesorios.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    imgaccesorios.setImageResource(R.drawable.accesorios2);
                    vibrator.vibrate(30);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :

                    notificaciones();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Este es el método notificaciones:

```
public void notificaciones(){

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

builder.setTitle("Your Title");

builder.setMessage("Some message...")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO: handle the OK
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();


}
```

Y este es el error que me sale al pulsar el botón:

```
06-10 08:08:17.043 2500-2500/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.

06-10 08:08:17.043 2500-2500/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-10 08:08:17.043 2500-2500/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:48)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:92)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:882)
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.Catalogos.notificaciones(Catalogos.java:360)
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.Catalogos$5.onTouch(Catalogos.java:223)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2831)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1863)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3046)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2792)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10228)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5344)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5180)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7306)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7145)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7416)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

06-10 08:08:17.043 2500-2500/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-10 08:08:17.043 2500-2500/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa, PID: 2500
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:48)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:92)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:882)
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.Catalogos.notificaciones(Catalogos.java:360)
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.Catalogos$5.onTouch(Catalogos.java:223)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2831)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1863)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3046)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2792)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10228)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5344)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5180)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7306)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7145)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7416)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteI
```

Quedo a la espera de vuestra ayuda para poder sacar el dialogo de pregunta, gracias por adelantado a todos :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se supone que este error es provocado porque tu `Activity` esta está intentando aplicar el tema de diálogo de `ActionBarActivity` que requiere de la `AppCompat.theme`.

Comprueba si en tu archivo `styles.xml`, tu tema principal tiene un `parent` que no sea igual al siguiente o no extienda del siguiente, es decir, que tenga el mismo comienzo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
 </resources>
```

Si no, abre tu `Manifest.xml` y en la etiqueta `<activity...>` de la que te da el error, comprueba el `android:theme`.

Otra posible razón del fallo puede estar en que, en tu clase no extiendes de `AppCompatActivity` o en caso de ser un fragmento de `Fragment`.

Espero haberte ayudado, compruébalo y me dices si a funcionado.

¡¡Mucha suerte en tu app!!

Comment: Tal cual!! estaba relacionado con el xml styles....Muchas gracias!

Comment: Yo tengo como theme en el manifest ```android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar```, pero este theme tiene como parent a ```Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar```. Como hereda de ```Theme.AppCompat``` no debería haber problema :(

Answer (score 8):

Si obtienes el error aun cuando el theme de tu activity es `Theme.AppCompat` (o hereda de él directa o indirectamente), la razón podría ser la siguiente.

El primer parámetro que recibe el Builder (para construir el Dialog) debe ser `this` en vez de `getApplicationContext()`. Esto aplica para los Activity.

Yo normalmente habría escrito `this`, pero había copiado la línea desde el interior de una clase anónima.

Más info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32373424/3692788